# SXA Grid Parameters: Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes

Tags: sxa

While using SXA v1.7.1 in the experience editor we sometimes were getting plagued by this exception after attempting to edit the style/grid parameters of a rendering on the page. It appears that some sort of double encoding is occuring when the layout details are being posted back to Sitecore.

```
[FormatException: Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx). Actual value: %7B113BEF7C-97E6-46CA-8CF3-916F7FAA8DE2%7D]
   Sitecore.Data.ID..ctor(String id) +207
   Sitecore.Data.ID.Parse(String value) +59
   System.Linq.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext() +145
   System.Linq.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext() +124
   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +436
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +69
   Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Grid.Commands.ShowGridPropertiesDialog.FillGridParameters(NameValueCollection contextParameters, DeviceDefinition device, NameValueCollection parameters, String fieldName, String value) +551
   Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Grid.Commands.ShowGridPropertiesDialog.UpdateLayout(NameValueCollection contextParameters, FieldEditorOptions fieldEditorOptions) +893
   Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Grid.Commands.ShowGridPropertiesDialog.Run(ClientPipelineArgs args) +160
```

We have implemented a temporary workaround by overriding the ShowGridPropertiesDialog command and checking each guid and decoding it if required.

Is this a bug?

Comment: This is a bug ..

Comment: Fix is located here - https://github.com/SitecoreSupport/Sitecore.Support.214239/tree/v9.0.1

Comment: @HarshBaid interesting to see Sitecore Support fixed this the other way around (they adjusted the rendering to prevent the double encoding vs our fix decodes the ID on the receiving end)

Comment: This patch file seems to break the Sitecore Forms screen.